# Loading translations from multiple backends

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I have React app using react-i18next, the translations are stored in two locations.  One set is stored locally to the app in a folder, the rest of the translations come from a remote API.

I am struggling to have both sets loaded into the app. Using the i18next-chained-backend plugin it seems that it only provides fallbacks if the first backend does not load the translations, i cant seem to configure it to load both sets of translations.

What is the best method of including translations from mulitple sources in a React based app?

Comment: The same question here

Comment: why don't you load translation on page load or language change and merge them ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to load translations from different places without using any dependency.
*(Only with npm packages 'react-i18next' and 'i18next')*

**These are the steps I followed:**

1. In `i18n.js`, set your client-side locale definitions.
2. Provide a list of namespaces to look-up translation keys in `ns` key in the same file.

   > Say the namespaces are ['translations', 'bkdynamic']
3. In your main react component, fetch your translations from an API endpoint.

   > In the given sandbox, API call is a mock which fetches `sampleTx.json` from your `public/` directory. This could be replaced to an actual endpoint which returns a JSON.
4. Using `i18next.addResourceBundle` API, load these translations for the language you require.

   > Load the newly fetched translations in namespace `bkdynamic` for the selected language.
   >   **Note:** While doing `i18next.addResourceBundle` call, set `deep` param to `true`; so that new translations are **extended.**
5. Rest of the translation APIs are same.

Live sandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/embed/i18next-muliple-files-p565v

- Local translations - *'Hello', 'Morning'*
- Translations loaded from another endpoint - *'Good'*

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to to handle that.

It works with classic **i18next-xhr-backend**.

You need to prepare custom function which composes the path:

```
const constructLoadPath = (languages, namespaces) => {
      if(namespaces[0] === 'basecontent'){
        return 'http://localhost:8080/api/i18n/{{lng}}/'
      }else {
        return '/locales/' + languages.join('+') + '/' + namespaces.join('+') + '.json';
      }
    }
```

then you need to provide this function to loadPath option of the backend

```
backend: {
  loadPath: constructLoadPath,
}
```