# React Typescript + Translations and languages

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to React typescript, I am trying to structure a very important scenario regarding translations.

I have a big payload of a data coming in from the API which includes all the translations required for the site. The idea is I should call that API on the first load of my app, store it in the frontend (I am trying to use redux), and load the default (en) translations on the first load. And I will have a language switch, which will again send another api call for that language translations, and so the translation state will change to the new selected language.

I am having a difficulty in structuring/caching this data efficiently at my end. Can someone help me with understanding how this data should be handled? Where shall I write this API call?

Comment: Take a look at https://react.i18next.com/

Comment: @pzaenger Thanks for your suggestion! I have tried this in my prototype. I have seen in many examples that while using i18next, translations are stored in static json files. Of course in my case as well, I will be getting json from the API. so how to handle those and store in translations which will be consumed by i18next. Also, do I need redux to store initial state of an application (initial language) in this case? sorry if this questions are stupid but been going through a lot of tutorials and blogs and I am very confused right now...

Comment: @Sonal I also recommend react i18next. Redux is not necessary for it to work to my knowledge. You just have to create static JSON files with translations for each localization (e.g. a JSON called 'fr', a JSON called 'en', etc.). There are built-in functions that handle language changing.

Comment: @fordat thank you for your suggestion and I totally understand your way and agree to it. But my translations are not in static files they come from an api. How do i handle that? Or translations coming from the database is a bad idea? 
Found this on stackoverflow. Will try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884796/loading-translations-from-multiple-backends